# Where and How, under the hood in NodeJS, readable._read() is getting called?

Tags: node.js, nodejs-stream

I am so curious about the below program.This program push the letters 'a' through 'z', inclusive , into a readable stream only when the consumer requests. I understand from the docs that `_read()` implementation is called by internal `Readable` class methods. If you run this program from terminal using the command `node app.js | head -c5` then we can see that `_read()` is only called 5 times when we only request 5 bytes and thus it prints only `abcde`.

I would like to know where in the Node source code this `_read()` implementation is called?. Or where in Node source code `_read()` is getting called 5 times when we request for 5 bytes of data?.

I am so curious to know this, if someone can help me figure out it that would be great.

```
var Readable = require('stream').Readable;
var rs = Readable();

var c = 97 - 1;

rs._read = function () {
    if (c >= 'z'.charCodeAt(0)) return rs.push(null);
    
    setTimeout(function () {
        rs.push(String.fromCharCode(++c));
    }, 100);
};

rs.pipe(process.stdout);

process.on('exit', function () {
    console.error('\n_read() called ' + (c - 97) + ' times');
});
process.stdout.on('error', process.exit);
```

Answer (score 0):

The **pipe function** is the triggering point.

- When you call `pipe` function, there's an `on('data', ...)` event triggered.
- This event extracts data for the stream using your **`_read`** implementation.
- Now your readable stream has the data populated.

About `head` command,

- The command looks for output util `-c` characters. Say `head -c 5` once 5 chars are printed, it signals the previous process to exit.
- On receiving this signal, the **node** process runs the exit function and terminates, hence stops executing `_read` further and prints number of characters read until then.

Here's the **Call Stack** of _read function captured from VS Code:

[image]

Comment: May I know how did you get this Stacktrace in VS code.

Comment: follow https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging and look for "Call stack" in VSCode debug pane.

Comment: Because of the command "node app.js | head -c5"  my _read() implementation called only 5 times and that means that it pushes only 5 bytes of data into the buffer. And hence we are getting only "abcde" as the output. But my assumption is that somewhere in Node source code there is a loop which will iterate only 5 times in this case and push only 5 bytes of data into the buffer. So I am expecting that kind of code somewhere in the source code.